# difficulty in handling correlation in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, token, correlation

i have identified the dynamic values in my website which i am handling through "regular expression extractor" still when i run the website the login request fails and throw error as token not found. please help,i m struggling...[this image contain the regEx extractor part and the failed login request also][1]

Comment: there is sensitive data in image please remove the current image and upload a new one with sensitive data masked. Also, to help you further please share response of request `/-7` with sensitive data masked

Comment: screenshot for `/-7` ?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing the response (at least partial) which you're getting for the `/-7` request containing this [hidden input with the token](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp), you can try locating it using "RegExp Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and see whether your regular expression matches something or not

[image]

One thing is obvious: [using regular expressions for extracting data from HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I would recommend considering switching to [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead:

[image]

Comment: thanks for response, i will try your suggestion.